# JavaDoc in an Eclipse Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

In our Android project, our code is JavaDoc'd and that generates everything properly. However, any reference to the Android API classes/functions results in a JavaDoc error and a link to the relevant information is not generated. Instead we get plaintext class names. How can we set up Eclipse to turn these into links to the online Android API reference (preferably) or a local copy (if necessary)?

Answer (score 39):

If you have the "Documentation for Android" package and the javadoc info still isn't showing up, make sure the Android library settings point to the right folder:

Project -> Settings -> Java Build Path, Libraries tab

Android X.X -> Android.jar -> Javadoc Location:
Should be something like "sdk_root/docs/reference/".

And to view the docs for a class in editor for example:

you should choose show attached java doc in web browser from to popup that appear when hover the cursor on some declaration.

Comment: I had a similar question and copied your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052199/adt-to-use-offline-docs-on-shiftf2)

Comment: To clarify a little bit, in Eclipse 3.7 (not sure if it looks different in older versions) it's Javadoc URL then the location path should be something like file:/C:/Users/username/android-sdks/docs/reference/ I had do change that from whatever URL it defaulted to and I have docs now.

Answer (score 9):

Install "Documentation for Android SDK" package using Android SDK and AVD Manager.

Comment: I've installed and nothing happened

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is new and might not been available on 2010 when the question been asked**
And these docs include android SDK docs which many developers need and google app engine too

[Detailed steps for the above link .. for indigo](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7)

[middle reference](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download)

Comment: Please fix the links. The first link is no longer available.