# Eclipse dont have java doc to show information about class and methods. how to attach those? +android

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

I'm
 working on android under eclipse holies environment. but my eclipse not helping me to find detail about class or method while writing code.
Ex: *Toast android.widget.Toast.makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)*

if i mouse hover on **makeText()** in above statement, getting following information

Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc

where and what do i need to attach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have installed the ADT plugin to Eclipse then you should make sure that you download the package called something along the lines of **"Documentation for Android SDK 2.2, 
API 8, revision 1"** or whatever. Have you gone through the entire installation guide for the Android SDK as posted on the official website? http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html this is the one I'm talking about. It's been discussed on SO before as well: [JavaDoc in an Eclipse Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268183/javadoc-in-an-eclipse-android-project)

If you have done all this, then http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jarjavadoc does a good job of explaining how to add Sources & Javadocs to existing Libraries in case something went wrong.

For example, this is how my Libraries path looks: [image: Weee!]

Go check and see how yours looks. Included is the location for the Javadocs normally (SDK Path/docs/reference/)

If you want to add the source code as well, see: 
http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/
& 
http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/01/browsing-android-source-in-eclipse/

Comment: the photo is broken and one of the links dont work but still one link is so greate (http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/)[http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/]