# How do I attach the sources for a library bundle in OSGi/Equinox/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, bundle, equinox

I [created a library bundle for `commons-lang3`](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html) and this works well. I can build the bundle, add a dependency and then use all the classes in this bundle in my plugins.

But I don't see the sources in the debugger.

What is the simplest way to create a source bundle for this library bundle?

PS: A library bundle is a plugin which contains the original JAR file; Eclipse doesn't compile the source again, it just adds the existing JAR to the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the source files to their own jar then create a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file with an 'Eclipse-SourceBundle' entry which specifies the symbolic name of your library bundle. Below is an example I have from the Felix jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Eclipse-SourceBundle: org.apache.felix.main;version="4.0.1";roots:="."
Bundle-Version: 4.0.1
Bundle-Name: Apache Felix Framework
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.felix.main.source
```

To be able to view the source in Eclipse make sure this source jar is in your PDE target (Windows->Preferences->Plugin Development->TargetPlatform). If your using Eclipse itself as the target platform just drop it in to your eclipse plugins folder.

Comment: So I need to create a *second* bundle, I can't simply add the sources to the library bundle?

Comment: I've only ever seen it done as 2 bundles, which makes sense to me as you usually wouldn't want to deploy the source code in the finished application. You may be able to add the source and the 'Eclipse-SourceBundle' entry to your library bundle, but I've not tried that.

Comment: @NickWilson Actually I do usually want to deploy source code in my finished applications. There are many benefits in doing so, and I would only *not* do it if I were building a closed-source commercial application. See my answer below for a way to include the source in the main bundle.

Answer (score 5):

You can include the sources under the `OSGI-OPT/src` path of the bundle; then they will be seen by the Eclipse debugger (not sure about other IDEs, as I only use Eclipse). I find this a lot simpler than creating a separate source bundle, because one artefact is easier to manage than two, and if you build with [Bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd) or [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/), we create bundles like this by default.

In the rare cases when you need to deploy to a resource-constrained environment, you can simply remove the `OSGI-OPT` directory from the bundle; this name is a convention for optional data that can be removed without affecting the operation of the bundle.

Incidentally our approach is inspired by UNIX executables, which often contain extra debugging symbols, and the [strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_%28Unix%29) command that removes them to create a smaller executable when desired.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly: It's enough to unpack the source JAR and copy the files into the folder `OSGI-OPT/src`? I don't have to add the folder to the `build.properties` or `MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: Yup, if you happen to use bnd, just add -sources: true

Comment: If using the maven-bundle-plugin in the pom.xml do <_sources>true</_sources>.  Also make sure you have set <packaging>bundle</packaging>.  The other gotcha in Eclipse is make sure to add the OSGI-OPT/src containing bundle to some Eclipse project's classpath as BJ Hargrave explains here "How do I view runtime bundle code while debugging?", Feb 2015, https://groups.google.com/d/topic/bndtools-users/tW4e-4TUOqw/discussion.