# How to include sources into OSGI bundle with Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin?

Tags: maven, osgi

I'm trying to build a very simple bundle, and I want to put the sources inside to be happy with debugging. Firstly, I was trying to add  `<sources>true</sources>` to `<instructions>`, according to BND instructions reference [here](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Format). 
Later, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720483/how-do-i-attach-the-sources-for-a-library-bundle-in-osgi-equinox-eclipse) discussion, I found, that it should be `<_sources>true</_sources>`, with underscore. Ok, now it started to try to put sources into the bundle, but still I have an error:

*Bundle ru.fragmental.beaver:blob.api:bundle:1.0-SNAPSHOT : Adding a sourcepath that is not a directory: D:\devel\fragmental.beaver\blob_api\target\generated-sources\annotations*

Can someone clarify what is wrong with my pom.xml? And, the second question is - why underscore is needed and where can I find docs about this?
My pom.xml and project structure are as follows:

pom.xml (xml schema and project tags were eaten by this text editor, but are present in the original file):

`<groupId>ru.fragmental.beaver</groupId>
    <artifactId>blob.api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Name>Blob API</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>ru.fragmental.beaver.blob.api</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>ru.fragmental.beaver.blob.api</Export-Package>
                        <_sources>true</_sources>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>`

The project structure is like this:

```
blob_api
   |
   |--src
   |   |
   |   |--main
   |        |
   |        |--java
   |             |
   |             |--ru.fragmental.beaver.blob.api(as nested dirs)
   |                        |
   |                        |
   |                        |--BlobPojo.java
   |                        |--BlobStorage.java
   |
   |--pom.xml
```

The whole project is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0CaRXyG1f1OWmk3UUJzSUZ6eEE)

Answer (score 0):

The proper bnd instruction is `-sources: true` (see http://bnd.bndtools.org/instructions/sources.html.) but in the mapping to XML elements for maven pom files, you cannot use -, so it is mangled to _. This is how maven-bundle-plugin mangles pom XML elements to bnd instructions.

The second issue appears to be a bug in the maven-bundle-plugin since it supplies a non-existent directory to bnd which then complains.

Comment: The question about underscore is mostly in not "why did they do it so?" - I guess, they had reasons, but in "How was I supposed to know about this?". Is there any piece of docs or specs that I missed? Or is it a common practice in maven, if <someInstruction> doesn't work - people shod try <_someInstruction> and, maybe <SoMeInStRuCtIOn> =) or whatever else? About the second issue - if this is a bug, than is there someone who managed to build bundle with sources via Maven? If so, please, share your experience.

Comment: They needed to map -sources to a valid xml tag for the pom file. - is not legit in xml element names. So it is mangled to _. This <_sources>. I don't work on maven-bundle-plugin, so I cannot comment on their documentation. Bnd support instructions that start with -, e.g. -sources. These are not copied into the resulting manifest. Bnd also supports variables which start with lower case letters; e.g. sources. These are also not copied to the resulting manifest. And bnd supports manifest headers starting with Upper case letters, e.g. Sources.