# Source not found, Edit Source Lookup Path

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing an android app with Eclipse, but whenever I debug my app I am getting.

ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread $ActivityRecord,Intent)line:2059 
and in the tab page body there is some red text that says `"Source not found"` and a button that says `"Edit Source Lookup Path..."`.

I have tried adding several paths via `"Edit Source Lookup Path..."` but can't see to find the one Eclipse is looking for.
And I have tried many solutions given online but still I my app is showing same message.

for my java code :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489325/source-not-found-in-android-emulator-while-debug-the-app-retrieving-data-from-we
(Code is working fine)

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found