# Confused about how to debug my class

Tags: java

everybody .I  have been working on this issue for hours .The problem is that  I cant debug my Database class.Once the break point hit this line

> final Database db=new Database(this);

I am trying to step into my Database class But eclips  says “Source not found” and shows a buton named  “Changed attach source” .So I have searched an explanaition on internet .I have found one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914187/why-does-the-eclipse-debugger-give-the-error-source-not-found-seemingly-withou)

to be able to fix  this error.I  have to find the where JDK is but I couldnt  under  this  location.Just JRE folder is available  There is no JDK

- C:\Program Files\Java

Comment: Time to install that JDK...

Comment: I'm confused, you said *step into my database class*, so that `Database` class is your own, inside your project, yes?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What is the Fully qualified name for Database class  ? 
You need to install JDK from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Then from JDK folder u will find file called src.zip which is include all the source code of the standard class's . But i believe 
this will not show the source for this Database class since its not standard class if you can get the fully qualified name of the class you can find its jar from 
http://www.findjar.com

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have JDK you should probably install it. Find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html)

**JDK/Java SDK** = Java Development Kit/Java Software Development Kit - what you need to write programs that require Java or use libraries written in Java. For example, if you were to write your own word-processing tool in Java.

**JRE** = Java Runtime Environment - what you need to run programs/software that require Java or use libraries written in Java. For example, OpenOffice requires the Java Runtime Environment

JRE allows you to run Java, whereas JDK allows you to program with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JDK from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. what you are having is JRE, but you dont have jdk. remove existing JRE and install JDK from the site.