# Can't debug anything in eclipse "Source not found"

Tags: java, debugging

I can't debug anything since yesterday and I don't know what it is. My programs run fine, and there is no error whatsoever. It doesn't matter which program i debug, I can make a Hello World-program and the debugger wont start. This is what I get:

Source not found, confirm perspective switch

[image: Source not found, confirm perspective switch]

If I click yes; Debugger info

[image: If I click yes; Debugger info]

If I click No, nothing happens.

I've tried configuring the debugger by adding all my projects to "Source", but that doesn't do it. :/ I've searched the web for more solutions but nothing works for me.

Comment: The first pic is asking you to switch to debug view. In the debug view you can view stack frame, enable/disable breakpoints, step over/in/out etc. So that you should do. The second pic says that debugger cannot find a source for the jar you are debugging. You need to edit look up path to point to a source jar. There needs to be a source jar corresponding to the jar used in the application for debugging.

Comment: The problem is that I'm adding my whole workspace in the path but doesn't help. And frankly I can't find any jar file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the source jar to the code you're trying to step into, then you can't see the code, because it's the executable version.

Meaning, for an example, if you're trying to debug the code in json.jar file, then you should have something like json-source.jar that you can attach to that file so you can step into it and see what's happening.
If you can elaborate more on your situation, we might be able to help more.

Comment: I can't find ANY jar file. :S

Comment: I don't see a reason for it not to go to debug mode. Do you mind sharing your code? And where exactly you're putting your breakpoints?

Comment: It doesn't matter if i set breakpoints, or where. I have tried to reinstall eclipse, switch workplace, make new project with new simple code. It will not debug. :/ This is the latest: https://i.imgur.com/WUdmEoa.png

Comment: I am not sure how to help from that picture. But all I can say is make sure you have your build path setup correctly.

Comment: I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14914297/7158942
But didn't work either. I only found "javafx-src" within the jdk1.8.0_111 folder though? Now I get another error: https://i.imgur.com/utcjuR3.png

Comment: In my current project I can debug the first lines until it gets to `" public SimpleWindow(int width, int height, String title) {`
`  frame = new JFrame(title);"` the JFrame ?

Comment: Hmm, when trying to fix where I suspect the problem lies, I got this: https://i.imgur.com/EA2jeVI.png

Comment: Starting to get ridiculous :/ downloaded this http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/ source file and tried with that. No help. :(

Comment: What do you see when you open preferences -> java -> installed JREs?

Comment: jre1.8.0_111(default) - but as you can see from my answer, I solved it. :) Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

OK I Solved it! Newbie alert!

I had TOO MANY debug sessions going on, and didn't know I had to terminate them. So while I clicked "Step into" I thought nothing happened, but I actually slowly ate the exceptions that was there. I also had an exception ticked, which means the debugger started from there and didn't go directly to my breakpoints.

WHY that exception is there I have no idea, since the code runs fine from the JFrame...

I terminated the debug sessions to the left, so now it's clean and fresh. And after unchecking the exception bs and only checking my breakpoints, it works:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ9mJ.png)

Comment: However I still have no idea as to where my jar-files are... :S