# Debugging java classes loaded by memory class loader

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader, remote-debugging

I am using a own class loader which stores classes in memory. Now I want to remote debug my application, but every time I hit a class in this class loader, Eclipse opens the corrent file but says "line: not available" in the debug view.

Does anybody know how I can provide the classloader with more information so that debugging works?

Thanks!

Comment: this might help you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found