# I am not able to write data in Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

My code looks like this:

```
public void method(String value,int row,int column) throws Exception {  
    try {    
        FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\sit2autouser1\\Desktop\\Newdatasheet.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet2");
        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(column);
        String cellContents = value;
        // Modify the cellContents here
        // Write the output to a file
        cell.setCellValue(cellContents);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\sit2autouser1\\Desktop\\Newdatasheet.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw (e);
    }
}
```

It is throwing error just before close and it is also corrupting the Excel file.
I am getting the same error, as soon as it reaches .write function it opens up a new tab which says "Source not found","Edit Source Look up path". And the heading of the tab is Integer.decode(String) line: not available.

Comment: cam please someone provide me an answer for this.Need it urgently.Thanks in advance

Comment: "it is throwing error" ... Could you be more specific about that part? Have you tried using apache POI ?

Comment: i am using apache POI.

Comment: plz post stake trace

Comment: Integer.decode(String) line: not available,i am getting this error

Comment: I don't see that line in the code you posted.

Comment: i am trying to write data into an existing excel sheet

Comment: Can you please check the fileout close command there is an extra special character .

Comment: sorry,that was while posting this question

Comment: it is giving the error on wb.write(fileOut);

Comment: Just add  fileOut.flush(); before fileOut.close(); and execute

Comment: its throwing the error when i am debugging it.And the error comes on this line wb.write(fileOut);

Comment: Please show the exact error, that is the full stack trace. Please don't do it in a comment but edit your question and provide it there. Shot in the dark: put `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);` before `cell.setCellValue(cellContents);`.

Comment: @ Axel Richter:When i used your code,eclipse is stating The static field Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING should be accessed in a static way.How do i do this??

Comment: `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);` *not* `cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);`. Uppercase `C` in `Cell`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet for creating workbook instance.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\sit2autouser1\\Desktop\\Newdatasheet.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
```

Comment: ,i am being able to create the instance.I am facing the issue when its reach the .write line.

Comment: I tried it with your code on my side, its working fine. can you mention error here?

Comment: when i am debugging it ,i am getting the same error.as soon as it reaches .write function,It opens up a new tab which says "Source not found","Edit Source Look up path".And the heading of the tab is Integer.decode(String) line: not available.I wanted to put up an image,but i dont have the rights can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting value properly. see the third line of code

Below is my working code:-

```
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

        wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).createCell(cellNum).setCellValue(input);

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(xlpath);

        wb.write(fos);

        fos.close();
```

OR

Make sure that in the remote debug configuration your eclipse project is selected.

Below is the reference, you can try that also:-

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found
```

Comment: I tried using your code but when i am debugging it ,i am getting the same error.as soon as it reaches .write function,It opens up a new tab which says "Source not found","Edit Source Look up path".And the heading of the tab is Integer.decode(String) line: not available.I wanted to put up an image,but i dont have the rights can you please help..

Comment: Is your excel file present on that location.Is that location have privileges by system to read/write.updated my answer and provide a reference. that might help you

Comment: yes the excel file is present in that location.its there on the desktop and does not have any priveleges.I tried adding my project remotedebug configuration,i am not sure if i did the right thing,but its still not working.Surprisingly this code was working fine before,and is working fine when i am running it,the problem appears only when i debug it.

Comment: In the debug window the line Integer.decode(String) line: not available is under Thread[main](Suspended(exceptionNumberFormatException))