# Issue w/ Java Photon Source Not Found during Debugging

Tags: eclipse

Stepping through in debug mode produces "Source Not Found" in Photon but not in Oxygen.

If I take a small set of classes, create a Java Project, and then put those classes in the SRC directory, under Oxygen without any special configuration I can step through the execution just fine in debugging mode, but get the "source not found" error in Photon even if I'm only stepping through those exact same classes.

What I tried in Photon

- adding the source of the project manually to Photon (after clicking the button you get when source isn't found). this didn't work but the project's own source is already part of the source path (under default)
- checking the checkbox for the JRE.

JRE: 1.8.0_181-b13
OS:  Windows 7 x64

Comment: If you want to report a bug, you should report it on https://www.eclipse.org/. Otherwise, you forgot to ask a question: please ask a question or at least describe the goal of posting this here.

Comment: In any case, you may want to look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel! I should have asked "what am I doing wrong." I think there's something fundamental and obvious that you're supposed to do in Photon that EVERYONE knows and doesn't even mention.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Please make a concrete example of how to reproduce it. Maybe in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ a JRE instead of a JDK is configured, so you can only see the `.java` files of the project but not the source of e. g. `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to turn off:

> Window->Preferences->Java->Debug->Use advanced source lookup

It worked for me.
See related bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537699