# "Source not found" in java debugger

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, parsing, debugging

Currently I am trying to simply step through my program in the debugger via 'f5'. However, each time I am met with "Source not found", & the debugger quits out despite the program actually running fine.

There are several other questions with similar problems. I tried those solutions - in particular the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found). However, still no luck after attempting to add the "source" via the "source-lookup" option in the debug menu.

Here is the code:

```
package com.xmlParsing;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class DomParsingMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        
        Document doc = db.parse("DictionaryPractice.xml");
        
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("definableterms");
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            
            Node p = nl.item(i);
            
            if(p.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {
                
                Element contents = (Element) p;
                String attribute = contents.getAttribute("Introduction");
                System.out.println(attribute);
                
            }
            
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

And here is the screen that I get post 'f5' press:

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you install jdk?

Comment: Yes, I can debug other programs fine EDIT - maybe I didn't, I'm not sure. Would my programs even run without it? My other programs run as they should.

Comment: Programs in eclipse will run because it has an inbuilt compiler. Does the jar you downloaded have the source code?

Comment: @Matthew as I can see in your print, you are using jre1.8.0_181. If i'm not wrong, you don't have the source of your .classses. You should download jdk, inside the jdk instalation folder, you have a src.zip. Inside this src you have the source of some of these org.w3c. Unzip it then go to Eclipse, find "Debug Configurations", then click on the tab "Source" > "Add" > now you have to select your folder with sources. Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download jdk, and repeat this attempt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found). If it still doesn't work, take a look at my prints, go to your jdk folder, find the src.zip

[image: .java location]

Then you unzip the src and you'll have all .java you'll need. Node.java is just an example of a class that you are using in your program.

[image: src]

Now you will have all sources and it will help you also with other sources you may need. It is also a good way to learn some great code.

Comment: Thanks for the help jhenrique :)