# Source Not Found Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

This question has been asked many times before, but out of the numerous solutions presented, none have remedied my issue.

Currently, I am using the Eclipse IDE for Java development. When debugging, I continue to run into the "Source not found" error, presented below, after I step into line 29.

[image]

As noted, I step into the line...

[image]

Bam. Source not found.

I have attempted a few remedies. I followed the numerous solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found), attempting to edit the source lookup & add the associated project. However, no luck with this method.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT**

Here is another image of my source folder. This should bring some clarity to what I have:

[image]

Comment: yes, I have done that, as noted above.

Comment: looks like you are not in the class yet.  I see that you have the java source file open, have you tried adding a breakpoint in this code?  Is this your own code?  Is it in the same package?

Comment: I have breakpoints in each of the source files, if that is what you are asking. No matter where the breakpoint is, I hit a "source not found" error.

Comment: Is Evaluator your own code? Is it in the same package?

Comment: Yes, Evaluator is my code & its all in the same package & project (the project being Caterpillar Practice). I'm making an edit now that will help you see what is actually in my source lookup.

Comment: Is the folder than your code is in marked as a src folder in your buildpath?

Comment: How do I change/check that? I have the normal src folder where the code resides in.

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm

Comment: Matthew,  Did it work?