# ADT to use offline docs on SHIFT+F2

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have the Android SDK documentation offline, however when I use the SHIFT+F2 combination in eclipse it tries to take me to the on-line site, even when I'm not connected to the internet. Isn't it supposed to take me to the offline docs?

I want to be able to use my offline docs with shift+f2.

I've looked through eclipse's preferences, but there seem to be no settings that could help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268183/javadoc-in-an-eclipse-android-project).

> If you have the "Documentation for Android" package and the javadoc
>   info still isn't showing up, make sure the Android library settings
>   point to the right folder:
>
> Project -> Settings -> Java Build Path, Libraries tab
>
> Android X.X -> Android.jar -> Javadoc Location: Should be something
>   like "sdk_root/docs/reference/".

thanks to Kevin Tighe,