# Eclipse Function / Method explanation missing

Tags: android, eclipse

my Eclipse doestn work as i want it in two terms.

Every method i want to use is described with arg0 arg1 arg2 instead of the real name
for Example:
getPrefs.getBoolean(arg0, arg1)
instead of 
getPrefs.getBoolean(key, defValue)

and also the explanation of the functions/methods is completely missing.

would be grateful if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you need to have the Javadocs/Source code attached to your project.

Right click on your project and select properties
Select "Java Build Path"
Then "Libraries"
Then whichever is your main Android API, expand and edit to set the "Source Attachment"/"Javadocs"

This should provide the java doc cues

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268183/javadoc-in-an-eclipse-android-project For clearer instructions

Comment: thanks for your answer. I dont get it completely yet sorry. If i klick edit to the source Attatchment what is at the moment set to : none, i get the message: select the location containing the source for android.jar ! how to find out what my location path is or where this file is located? thanks a lot!!!

Comment: That link I posted earlier has correct instructions. Just change the Android.jar javadoc to whatever "{sdk_root}/docs/reference/" is for your computer. Just set that up on my own computer and it worked

Comment: Sorry I didnt see the Link back then. I m new to android and this forum. Thanks a lot!!! it works now!

Comment: Ah since you're new, when you've got an answer to your question its good to mark it as "accepted" by giving it the green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. Get src.zip file

Download dk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz file from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Extract it. The file contains the src.zip file.

2. Copy the file in the JDK directory
3. Attach the file in the Source Attachment Configuration.

Open Eclipse.
Open a Class.
Control+click in a method.
(A window appears which says "No source found")
Click in Attach
Click in External Localitation
Click in External File
Look for the directory with the src.zip file
Attach it.

[Control+click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X08xl.jpg)
[Attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li2W1.png)

Youtube explanation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx9l72NBVC8

Comment: You should post all the essential information *in your answer itself*, not in links inside your answer, if at all possible