# Why can't Eclipse find the JavaDoc?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have installed the Java3D API and the documentation. Here is where I got the documentation from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html

now, i followed these instructions to install the JavaDoc for Eclipse:

[JavaDoc in an Eclipse Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268183/javadoc-in-an-eclipse-android-project/5134343#5134343)

I set the path of the documentation for the jars to the location of the documentation on my computer. When I click on an Object name in Eclipse, the popup window pops up, but it says "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found." Is there anything I'm missing here? It would be a lot more convenient if the info could just show up in the popup window instead of me rooting through the documentation by hand.

---

edit

this is that my eclipse looks like right now:

[image]

Here is what i have the path set to:

http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2-latest/

Still no luck, i still get the same popup saying it can't find the javadoc.

Comment: Please check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse-attach-source-javadoc-to-a-library-via-a-local-property)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally that should do the trick, but I'll just try to rephrase the instructions you have previously followed, maybe you missed a step:

1. Right click your project -> Properties
2. Select `Java build path` in the tree on the left
3. Select `Libraries` tab
4. **[Skip if using maven]** Add your library to the classpath
5. **[Only if using maven]** Expand the maven library by clicking on the small arrow in front of it
6. Expand the 3d jar options by clicking on the small arrow in front of it
7. Click on the `Edit` button and select your zip location in `Archive path`
8. If you open the zip, you'll see that all the documentation is in the folder `java3d-1_4_0-doc`. You should add that to the `Path within archive` input box
9. Click ok, ok, ok...

This should set you up. You could also extract the archive to a desire folder or use the online URL (the one that [bitwave suggested](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2-latest/), but please be aware that you'll be needing a constant internet connection to access it) and specify whichever you want in the `Javadoc URL` input box.

Cheers

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and neither of them worked, I've also tried extracting the JavaDoc from the zip and using it that way with no luck, ill edit my post to show you what i have done

Comment: So did I, and a simple class containing a test method, will display the javadoc when hovering the cursor (or clicking F2) above the J3DBuffer  declaration `J3DBuffer buffer;`. It's a longshot but maybe there's something wrong with eclipse. Could you try with a fresh install and see if it reproduces?

Comment: Could you please tell us what the problem was? I'm very curious :)

Comment: There is also a "validate" button in Eclipse near the place you enter the javadoc path. It can be useful to check if you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your problem ;)

The documentation is a collection of HTML-files. ([like this](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2-latest/))

You have to unpack the zip and then you can view this in a browser like Internet Explorer or Google Chrome via File->Open File...

To use the Java-Doc, a special JAR-file must provided by Oracle. In this JAR-file there are .java-files with

```
/**
 * This is JavaDoc 
 */

/*
 *This is a typical comment...
 */
```

Oracle haven't provided this JAR yet, so you can only use the Browser...

Hope I can helped you...