# This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I started developing on Android and I'm encountering some problems with eclipse:

there is image:

[image]

What should I do to show javadoc?

Comment: what package contains your ltInflater's class ?

Comment: really?? its on the picture itself - android.view.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268183/javadoc-in-an-eclipse-android-project

Comment: @RobinChander .. and i'm the one who put the picture in the right place :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to download and attach the source code.

1) Open the SDK Manager and download "Sources for Android SDK" under the latest or appropriate API.

2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click any Android class or method then click the "Attach Source Code" button in the window that appears.  Next select "External Folder" and navigate to `<android-SDK>\sources\android-xx`.

- `<android-SDK>` is the folder that holds your SDK
- `xx` refers to your appropriate API