# Javadoc could not be found in the attached source

Tags: java, android

when I put the mouse on function in java to know the definition it show me this msg 
Note:This element has no attached Javadoc and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached source

what Is the problem and what can I do ?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14695392/1454261

Comment: sry but I can't found the "Sources for Android SDK" in the SDK Maneger

Comment: You don't have the sources for android, just the jar file.  It may be wise to read the documentation starting at http://developer.android.com/about/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is because you probably didn't download the documentation for the Android SDK version you are using, or in case you are using an external library, chances that documentation is not there are quiet possible too, either way if you want to add the documentation for your android SDK version follow the steps below:

You need to download and attach the source code.

In the SDK Manager, download "Sources for Android SDK".

Go to any Android class or method then click the "Attach Source Code" button in the window . Next select "External Folder" and navigate to your documentation folder for that version.

Regards!